# Copy only directories from a command prompt

Tags: cmd

I want to copy only directories (it's files and sub directories) within the current directory from a command prompt.

I've already copied all the files in the current directory using this command.

```
copy * d:\copyfolder
```

I've tried these for individual folders. To copy a folder:

```
XCOPY C:\utils D:\Backup\utils /i
```

To copy a folder including all subfolders.

```
XCOPY C:\utils* D:\Backup\utils /s /i
```

But couldn't find a way to copy only directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried these for individual folders.
To copy a folder:

```
XCOPY C:\utils D:\Backup\utils /i
```

To copy a folder including all subfolders.

```
XCOPY C:\utils\* D:\Backup\utils /s /i
```

But this command can help, not overwriting any files.

```
XCOPY C:\utils\* D:\Backup\utils /s /i /d
```

Answer (score 1):

From the command line this should work to copy all folders with subdirectories and files:

```
for /d %a in (*) do xcopy "%a\*.*" "d:\copyfolder\%a\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
```

Comment: Are all those flags necessary to copy only folders?

Comment: @MxyL It depends if you want to copy hidden and system files, but as it is presented it is a fairly reliable method of duplicating folders.  An added bonus is that it is easy to remember "She likes KFC"